# Reading certain integers from a text file into a Array List

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I have to read two sets of integers in a text file. One is the number of credits that a student can have and then the next integer is a letter grade on a test. I can read the integers into an ArrayList, but the issue is that I want to read first the amount of credit they have, then choose which ArrayList to add them to, under a certain amount of credit or over a certain amount. I don't want to add the amount of credits up, just the grade they received. I have 25 lines of integers in the text file, first is the amount of credit, then a space, and then the grade. I only need to record the grade, not the credit amount. 
Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList <Integer> over15credits = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList <Integer> under15credits = new ArrayList<>();
        FileReader myReader = new FileReader("geomClass.txt");
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(myReader);

        while(fileIn.hasNextInt())
        {
            if(fileIn.nextInt() >= 15)
            {
                over15credits.add(fileIn.nextInt());

            }
            else
            {
                under15credits.add(fileIn.nextInt());
            }
            System.out.println(over15credits);
            System.out.println(under15credits);
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("!!FILE NOT FOUND!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work? If not, what problem/error do you have?

Comment: It is just adding all of the integers together in the arrays(including the credits), when I print out both ArrayLists, it will not crash but send around 20 lines of Arrays instead of just one line of an Array. But, if I only print out 1 ArrayList, the program will print it out and then crash. Other than that, the program will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `fileIn.nextInt()` it reads and consumes the number so that when you call `fileIn.nextInt()` again it will read the number after that.

Most likely you meant to use a variable so that you can use the number you just read.

```
    int num = fileIn.nextInt();
    if (num >= 15)
        over15credits.add(num);
    else
        under15credits.add(num);
```

You want to use the same number you just read not another number.

FYI you can also write it like this.

```
    int num = fileIn.nextInt();
    (num >= 15 ? over15credits : under15credits).add(num);
```